# UIActionSheet does not show in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios-simulator, uiactionsheet, ios7.1, ios8.1

This is a result image once I call the code for [actionsheet showInview:self.view]in iOS 7.1 simulator. 
[image]

This is a piece of code for iOS 8, works perfect, and for iOS 7.1, for which I am facing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for that. I have re-uploaded.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution. As I have 2 ChildViewController under Parentcontroller, I replaced my call [actionsheet showInView:self.view] with [actionsheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view]. Then it works like a charm :)